# How can I show only first level terms on a dropdown taxonomy exposed filter?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a 2 level taxonomy tree: Countries and cities. I also have a view of content, all of which are marked by first level terms (countries) of that vocabulary.

My taxonomy tree is like that:

- Country 1

  - City 1
  - City 2
  - City 3
- Country 2

  - City 4
  - City 5

In an exposed filter over the view, I want to show only the first level terms (countries) as options. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to [How Can I add a Hierarchical taxonomy Select in views filters and when editing content in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/23629/18878)

I will say that the easiest method I can see is to add an exposed field by the name of "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)" this way you can select the vocabulary(unfortunately only one) and also select the depth.